# MvvmCross and Xcode Storyboard

Tags: xamarin.ios, storyboard, mvvmcross

### **The storyboard xcode are supported in mvvmcross v3?**

```
If yes, how? There is an example?
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

MvvmCross doesn't really fit that well with Storyboards

The reason is because Storyboards have some logic in them (eg `Segue` navigation) which really belongs inside actions in the MvvmCross ViewModels.

With that said... if you just want to take advantage of data-binding then you can... just:

- add the MvvmCross assembly references
- modify your Storyboard app so it runs some minimal setup code
- use the `Mvx*ViewController` base classes instead of the `UI*ViewController` classes
- and similarly use `MvxTableViewCell` (or similar) for the base class for any `TableViewCell`'s you use.

There's no documentation around for this at the moment... but there is one sample - posted under the very odd title of 'eh' - https://github.com/slodge/eh - it's just a simple master-detail pair of views and it needs to be built against recent binaries - e.g from https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Binaries/tree/master/XS-iOS-Mac

Comment: Solved! It works very well. Thank you very much. The framework is really nice.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is really the SO way but Stuart and others have a better answer IMHO to this question when it was asked at a later date. See the answers to this question [MVVMCross support for Xamarin.iOS Storyboards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22126929/mvvmcross-support-for-xamarin-ios-storyboards)

I am answering here just to tie up the Q&A

**UPDATE**
MVVMCross 3.5.1 Now has a FromStoryboard attribute so that you can have some views which are Storyboard based. See http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2015/05/351-release.html

Thanks

Pat