# MVVMCross support for Xamarin.iOS Storyboards

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

With support for XS integration of iOS storyboards about to make the Stable stream, I would love to be able to use this feature in conjunction with MVVMCross.

Fundamentally it does seem a little like it should not work, as with storyboards indicate navigational hierarchy in the view project, rather than a viewmodel project like MVVMCross.

But it would be awesome if there is a way to make the 2 work together.

Does anyone know how this might be achieved?

Cheers, Tristan

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is at least one sample published showing the use of Storyboards - the rather oddly named `eh` - https://github.com/slodge/eh

This sample worked by:

- letting the Storyboard control the navigation
- using `MvxViewController` as a VC base class (in place of `UIViewController`)
- manually setting the `ViewModel` in one case - by setting it directly **before** calling `base.ViewDidLoad()` - see https://github.com/slodge/eh/blob/master/storyb/RootViewController.cs#L23
- manually setting the `Request` in one case - during the `Segue` navigation - see https://github.com/slodge/eh/blob/master/storyb/RootViewController.cs#L40

Using approaches like this it's pretty easy to add Mvx Data-Binding to an application that is primarily driven by the Storyboard.

---

Alternatively, if developers would prefer to let the Mvx `ShowViewModel` navigation system control the flow of screens - but would also prefer those screens to be designed within a storyboard, then this is possible by developing a normal MvvmCross application, but using a custom `Presenter` which loads ViewControllers from the storyboard.

In v3.1.1 of MvvmCross, you can do this at the `ViewsContainer` level:

- override a class `MyContainer` from `MvxTouchViewsContainer.cs`
- override the method `protected virtual IMvxTouchView CreateViewOfType(Type viewType, MvxViewModelRequest request)` - see https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/b8545752f28f4e569efeaa397c3085b0373e4d8b/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Touch/Views/MvxTouchViewsContainer.cs#L40
- in this override, load your Storyboard-based ViewControllers:

  ```
   protected override IMvxTouchView CreateViewOfType(Type viewType, MvxViewModelRequest request)
   {
       return (IMvxTouchView)UIStoryboard.FromName("MyStoryBoard", null)
                                         .InstantiateViewController(viewType.Name);
   }
  ```
- create your `MyContainer` during `Setup` -

  ```
  protected override IMvxTouchViewsContainer CreateTouchViewsContainer()
  {
      return new MyContainer();
  }
  ```
- that should just then work...

Comment: the second approach is definitely proper way to do that as long as we develop real cross-platform app. It is better to navigate using ShowViewModel and share this logic among the platforms.

Comment: So - presumably this would involve a Storyboard without Segues defined.  Any Segues that were defined would be ignored?

Comment: The second approach seems to be nice - but it is crashing on me during InstantiateViewCOntroller. Probably navigation will not be easily possible then anyways.

Comment: This approach fails in my case. The result is that it can't convert UIViewController to IMvxTouchView. It creates a generic UIViewController instance. Do you have any idea about why this is happening?

Comment: Ask a good question - with the steps you've gone through and the necessary code for people to understand where it's going wrong for you - people will try to help

Comment: Hi I've followed the steps above but when the overloaded CreateViewOfType is called I get an InvalidCastException because I cannot cast UIKIt.UIViewController to IMvxTouchViewSystem.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'UIKit.UIViewController' to type 'Cirrious.MvvmCross.Touch.Views.IMvxTouchView'.

Comment: Hi, I have problems like Stuart and sisterray

Comment: See @kwl's answer. Storyboards are supported in MvvmCross now.

Answer (score 11):

In a large project, keeping all views in a single storyboard may be daunting.

I prefer creating one storyboard per view; I modified the Container in Stuart's answer to look for a storyboard matching the view class, and fall back to the main storyboard if not found:

```
public class StoryBoardContainer : MvxTouchViewsContainer
{
    protected override IMvxTouchView CreateViewOfType(Type viewType, MvxViewModelRequest request)
    {
        UIStoryboard storyboard;
        try
        {
            storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName(viewType.Name, null);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName("StoryBoard", null);
        }
        return (IMvxTouchView) storyboard.InstantiateViewController(viewType.Name);
    }
}
```

Caveat 1: To instantiate viewcontrollers this way, you **must** set the Storyboard ID in the editor:

[image: Storyboard ID]

Caveat 2: Make sure your views inheriting `MvxViewController` have the constructor `public MyView(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)`, as this is used to instantiate the view controllers from the storyboard.

Comment: One could also make a container that support both Storyboards and Xibs. Maybe this could be added to the default container in MvvmCross?

Comment: Make sure your view class inherits from MvxTouchView and that you have implemented the constructor in caveat 2 above. Otherwise no clue, sorry.

Comment: Has any one tried this approach and found that none of their AutoLayout Constraints were respected? I applied constraints via Designer that behave as expected, in the Designer but at runtime they are a complete mess

Comment: Thanks for this. I am trying to use this approach. This works fine on the simulator. However, when running on the iOS Device, The Exception is not getting caught. The app simply crashes saying 'NSInvalidArgumentException : Could not find Storyboard named xxx' . Any idea why this happens only on the device?

Comment: I believe simulator is case insensitive regarding file names, while device is case sensitive; make sure you are using the correct case. Also avoid any exotic characters in the filename.

Comment: @GeirSagberg Thanks for that. I should have told you that I slightly modified the code you have written. I am working on an app which was previously developed without using Storyboards, i.e. all the views were created in code. Now I am planning to use storyboards for the new views. So I added a try-catch around (IMvxTouchView) storyboard.InstantiateViewController(viewType.Name) as well. Please refer to this thread where I have explained my problem in detail - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28598392/monotouch-exception-not-getting-caught-on-device

Answer (score 8):

Storyboard support is now a part of MvvmCross. Use the one ViewController per Storyboard approach as described in Geir's answer, setting the Storyboard ID, and decorate your MvxViewController partial classes with `[MvxFromStoryboard]`. See sample code on my [blog](http://kerry.lothrop.de/ios-ui-with-mvvmcross/).

Comment: Useful reference for setting name of storyboard in MvxFromStoryboard decorator: https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/platform/ios-user-interfaces-approaches#storyboards

Answer (score 3):

I've made a sample project (TipCalc) using mvvmcross and ios storyboard: https://github.com/nicruo/TipCalc.Storyboard

Comment: your demo works. I tried to copy this sample and it seems that I did somethig wrong. Can you please help? https://github.com/slown1/Xamarin.iOS-Storyboard